# How do I code the example model object in the PreviewProvider in SwiftUI?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have some code but I don't have all of it. I understand the basics of the code that I have regarding SwiftUI and Core Data but I don't know how to code the redFox model example in the following code.

I tried to code redFox myself but was unable to do so.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimalCell : View
{
    let model: AnimalCellModel

    var body: some View
    {
        HStack
        {
            Text(model.image)
            Text(model.commonName)
            Text(model.familyName)
            Text(model.scientificName)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
public enum AnimalCellPreviews : PreviewProvider
{
    public static var previews: some View
    {
        AnimalCell(model: .redFox)
    }
}
#endif
```

I should see the preview but can't because the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `redFox` as a static property to the `AnimalCellModel`:

```
extension AnimalCellModel {
    static var redFox = AnimalCellModel(...)
}
```

Then you can use it with the `.redFox` syntax like shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for but the standard preview code is as follows:

```
#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

So in your case it should be:

```
#if DEBUG
struct AnimalCell_Previews : PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        AnimalCell(model: RedFox())
    }
}
#endif
```

Assuming you have a RedFox struct or class

Comment: No it should be: AnimalCell(model: .redFox). How do I code .redFox, not RedFox() assuming .redFox is a struct or class. What does the code for .redFox look like assuming it is a struct or class?